# What exception should be thrown if the key asked for, doesn't exist?

Tags: java, exception

I'm working on a non-generic class which is supposed to implement a method that finds an object based on an integer key. The task says: "If the element being searched for doesn't exist, throw an exception."

Which exceptions would be relevant in this case? Or should I just make my own 'NotFoundException' class by extending Exception?

Would these be of any help?
- NotBoundException
- AclNotFoundException

Comment: Java's IllegalArgumentException seems good enough imo

Comment: *Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument* -- I wouldn't go as far as to say it's *illegal* or *inappropriate* to search for something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`NoSuchElementException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) might be good enough. Although documentation says *Thrown by the nextElement method of an Enumeration to indicate that there are no more elements in the enumeration.* so it might be a little surprising to see it in other contexts.

If you don't have a generic "not found" exception on your class path ([`javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.6/jersey/javax/ws/rs/NotFoundException.html), or [`javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityNotFoundException.html) for instance), I'd say the best option is to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the caller of the method is supposed to handle the exception or it should pass it to its caller. For example:

```
uiAction()
  appAction()
    daoFindByKey(int i)
```

if `daoFindByKey(int i)` throws an exception and the `appAction()` should somehow handle it than throw a checked `Exception` or a suitable subclasses. Otherwise throw a runtime exception or a suitable subclass.